# Android RelativeLayout editview how to make a text box bigger?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-edittext

I'm trying to make a text box about 3 lines high but also the textbox will also expand depending on the amount of information entered. I've used `wrap_content` which displays as one line and I've used `android:layout_height="150dp"`, however the text box does not expand. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmailCompose"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEmailSubject"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textSubject"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/emailCompose" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found the code required. It may help others.

```
*android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:minHeight="120dp" 
android:inputType="textMultiLine"*
```